# How to get the time when app launches in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store the app launch time in sqlite and use that time for the next launch in the functionality .. for that i am using

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
String data = format.format(new Date(19900101));
System.err.println("Time is.."+format.format(19900101));
```

I stuck how to get the time dynamically in format of yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.Even though using this code i am getting 1970-01-01..Please suggest me right way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change  your code to

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
String data = format.format(new java.util.Date());
System.err.println("Time is.."+data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You able to take time via this

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
```

OR change your code like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss");
String data = format.format(new Date());
System.err.println("Time is.."+format.format());
```

Thanks.